# Java, Java VM, Java Platform, 

Tags: jvm, java

Can someone explain the differences of the Java Platform SE (6), Java, Java VM, etc.? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java is the programming language defined by the [Java Programming Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/). Java VM is the virtual machine as defined by the [Java Virtual Machine Specifications](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html). The Java SE is the virtual machine packaged along the standard libraries and tools.

In compiler construction terms, Java is the **source language** whereas JVM is the **target language**.

Comment: Strictly speaking, JVM refers to the target platform rather than the target language (Java bytecode).

Answer (score 1):

In brief: Java is a catch-all for the language and platform combined. The Java VM is what the Java language and platform run on, but can support other languages as well. Java SE is the base language and platform bundle (developer's kit / runtime) targeted for desktop/applet development. Java EE then would be geared toward server and "enterprise" development.

Answer (score -1):

java is the language you are coding with

for example : `HttpServlet` is a java class, but it's not part of java SE, because it's part of the EE witch means enterprise edition. so java distinguish between SE packages and EE packages

and finaly all those package are executed in a JVM, a programme that runs java classes.
Hope that help

Comment: This doesn't adds anything over the existing answers